# Js script to toggle visibility on divisions does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this is my function. I have 3 buttons in one section and I want them to change division on click. First I have tried jQuery function but it didn't work for me than I tried to achieve this with this function but something is wrong probably, could you tell me why ?

Here is code:

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".clients").forEach(function(client) {
    client.style.display = 'none';
  });
  document.querySelector("#" + id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.clients1 {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.clients2 {
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.clients3 {
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="clients" id="clients">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="">
                <img src="images/img4-pad.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="clients-img-character ">
                <img src="images/img5-character.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-left clients1" id="clients1">
                <h1>aaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa<a>aaaaaaaaaaaa</a></p>
                <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
                <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
                <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-left clients2" id="clients2">
                <h1>aaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
                <p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa<a>aaaaaaaaaaaa</a></p>
                <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
                <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
                <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-left clients3" id="clients3">
                <h1>aaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
                <p>cccccccccccccccccccccccccc</p>
                <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa<a>aaaaaaaaaaaa</a></p>
                <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
                <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
                <span>aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <button class="clients-buttons" onclick="toggle_visibility()" id="clients-buttons1"></button>
            <button class="clients-buttons" onclick="toggle_visibility()" id="clients-buttons2"></button>
            <button class="clients-buttons" onclick="toggle_visibility()" id="clients-buttons3"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try using `getComputedStyle` instead of `style` prop

Comment: I don't understand your logic. If 2 and 3 are not showing, then 1 is already showing, so setting its style to `block` won't change anything.

Comment: Than how it should look like to display properly ?

Comment: Can you explain what the logic is supposed to be? Why are there 3 buttons if they all do the same thing?

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It has a `.toggle()` method that handles all the details.

Comment: I have tried to do it with jQuery but also it wasn' working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".client").forEach(function(client) {
    client.style.display = 'none';
  });
  document.querySelector("#" + id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#clients1 {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#clients2 {
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#clients3 {
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-4 text-left client" id="clients1">
  <h1>aaaa</h1>
  <p>aaaaa</p>
  <p>aaaaa<a>aaaaaa</a></p>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
</div>
<div class="col-4 text-left client" id="clients2">
  <h1>aaaa</h1>
  <p>bbbbbbbbbb</p>
  <p>aaaaa<a>aaaaaa</a></p>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
</div>
<div class="col-4 text-left client" id="clients3">
  <h1>aaaa</h1>
  <p>ccccccccc</p>
  <p>aaaaa<a>aaaaaa</a></p>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <button class="clients-buttons" onclick="toggle_visibility('clients1')" id="clients-buttons1"></button>
  <button class="clients-buttons" onclick="toggle_visibility('clients2')" id="clients-buttons2"></button>
  <button class="clients-buttons" onclick="toggle_visibility('clients3')" id="clients-buttons3"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Now it display 3 div at the same time

Comment: @Buszek try now

Comment: Now it hides whole clients section

Comment: I did, I can see that it works here but It doesn't in my files.

Comment: @Buszek you need to pass `id` to `toggle_visibility()` and change `<div class="col-4 text-left clients2" id="clients2">` to `<div class="col-4 text-left clients" id="clients2">` (remove number from `clients2`) or better change it to `client` in HTML and JS

Comment: It works now but without clicking any button 3 of this div display at the same time, after refreshing the website.

Comment: @Buszek this is different problem, ask new question and accept answer if it's correct

Answer (score 0):

`xxx.style.display` doesn't get the style from CSS, it only gets inline style. Since none of the divs have `style` attributes, this is empty for all of them, so none of the `if` conditions succeed. You need to use `getComputedStyle` to merge in CSS.

You should also use `else if`, since the 3 conditions are mutually exclusive.

```js
function toggle_visibility() {
  var clients1 = document.getElementById("clients1");
  var display1 = getComputedStyle(clients1).getPropertyValue("display");
  var clients2 = document.getElementById("clients2");
  var display2 = getComputedStyle(clients2).getPropertyValue("display");
  var clients3 = document.getElementById("clients3");
  var display3 = getComputedStyle(clients3).getPropertyValue("display");
console.log(display1, display2, display3);
  if (display1 == 'none' && display3 == 'none') {
    clients2.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else if (display1 == 'none' && diplay2 == 'none') {
    clients3.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else if (display2 == 'none' && display3 == 'none') {
    clients1.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.clients1 {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.clients2 {
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.clients3 {
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-4 text-left clients1" id="clients1">
  <h1>aaaa</h1>
  <p>aaaaa</p>
  <p>aaaaa<a>aaaaaa</a></p>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
</div>
<div class="col-4 text-left clients2" id="clients2">
  <h1>aaaa</h1>
  <p>bbbbbbbbbb</p>
  <p>aaaaa<a>aaaaaa</a></p>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
</div>
<div class="col-4 text-left clients3" id="clients3">
  <h1>aaaa</h1>
  <p>ccccccccc</p>
  <p>aaaaa<a>aaaaaa</a></p>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaaa</span>
  <span>aaaaa</span>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <button class="clients-buttons" onclick="toggle_visibility()" id="clients-buttons1"></button>
  <button class="clients-buttons" onclick="toggle_visibility()" id="clients-buttons2"></button>
  <button class="clients-buttons" onclick="toggle_visibility()" id="clients-buttons3"></button>
</div>
```